# Updating a model using Django Rest Framework and ViewSets

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm new to DRF, and I'm trying to build a webhook that gives out lists of model objects and also allows these objects to be updated. I followed this tutorial http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/, and have the following serializer and view:

```
class Task(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ('user', 'task', 'unixTime')
```

View:

```
class RequestViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows reqests to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = Task.objects.filter(done = False).order_by('-unixTime')
    serializer_class = Task
    paginate_by = None

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object_list = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        serializer = self.get_serializer(self.object_list, many=True)
        return Response({'results': serializer.data})
```

I'm pretty sure I have to include a `def update` under `def list`, but the online resources I found were a bit unclear on how to implement them and what they do. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@hackerman, Hmm..., if you followed the next step,

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/#urls

You will get an api address, it may looks like http://localhost:8000/task/1/,  assume here is a task obj (id=1) in your db. Please open it in your browser and check that api works or not.

And then, you need a http client ([requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) is a good choice) to create a PUT request with json string data.

Hope those can help.

Answer (score 2):

May be you just need to rename the serializer.

```
class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
```

And don't forget replace in the viewset

```
serializer_class = TaskSerializer
```

After it you can remove your list method, because it is standard.

Comment: @hackerman, cool name,  'Task' is your Model class name, so you have to change ModelSerializer class name. typo error ? :D

Comment: @gzerone, thanks! 'Task' was a typo on my part, nice catch. I fixed that, but still can't figure out how to update objects. Do you know what kind of code or request I would need to write to select objects and update their 'done' field?